# I can't delete a reference to a specific task in angularfire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have what might be somewhat of a unique angularfire setup where the path to a task is the week and day  of a task.

```
//for example this references a day collection that has tasks as children
var ref = new Firebase("https://talllly.firebaseio.com/tasks/" + $scope.currentWeek + '/' + day.$id);

$scope.currentWeek and day.$id are timestamps.
```

My problem is I can't seem to access that child task to be able to delete it. How can I access the individual tasks so I can delete them?

here's the view

```
<section class="col user-tasks" user-color color="{{profile.name}}">
    <form ng-submit="addTask(task, user); task = null;">
      <input placeholder="What are you working on today?" ng-model="task"/>
    </form>
    <ul class="tasks-list">
      <li ng-repeat="day in week | reverseArray">
        <span ng-show="day">{{getDisplayDate(day.$id) | date:'EEEE, MMMM d'}}</span>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="(key, task) in day | orderBy:'doneTime' | reverse" ng-show="task.addedBy === profile.name">
              <div class="row input-container">
                <div class="small-1 columns">
                  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.complete" ng-change="change(task, day)">
                </div>
                <div class="small-10 columns">
                  <input type="text" ng-model="task.text" ng-change="update(task)">
                </div>
                <div class="small-1 columns">
                  <span ng-click="delete(day, task)">x</span>
                </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

Also, on a related note but if something.$id is the first value of the object how can I access the -JXYiowyf-UerL3NeDm_ level of a task?

Edit, update to show where I'm getting tasks:

```
var populateTasks = function(date){
   var tasks = "https://talllly.firebaseio.com/tasks/" + getWeekStart(date);
   $scope.ref = new Firebase(tasks);
   var sync = $firebase($scope.ref);
   $scope.week = sync.$asArray();
 };
```

Update: 
I was able to get it working by recreating the functionality piece by piece. I'm still not entirely sure what's going on but my delete function now looks like this:

```
$scope.deleteTask = function(key, task, day){
  var sync = new Firebase(FBURL + '/tasks/' + $scope.currentWeek + '/' + day.$id);
  var deleteList = $firebase(sync);
  deleteList.$remove(key)
  .then();
};
```

Comment: Every object in a collection has an implicit `$id` property. That is the value you need to pass to `$remove`.

Comment: My $id property seems to be a timestamp and not the firebase $id. I'm not sure why yet but I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: How are you getting the item? I assume you are using AngularFire's `$asArray()` somewhere, but it doesn't show in your code above.

Comment: I get a week of tasks using populateTasks(). I added the code for that above.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure why you're getting those `$id`s. Can you set up a minimal reproduction? You can do that by clicking the Code Snippet button when you're editing your question.

Comment: We need moaaar input! :) Show us how these parts work together and we'll get you fixed up.

Comment: I'm working on a plunkr with all the latest. I'm going back through and re-implementing all the functionality piece by piece. The weird thing so far is that the $id is working properly...

Comment: Actually, @FrankvanPuffelen , $remove accepts either an index or the record from the array, not the $id (firebase key).

Comment: Yeah, I just answered that to another question earlier today. Didn't realize that was the same problem as here. I'll mark as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularfire, remove method returns 'Invalid record; could not find key', what should it be happenning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027829/angularfire-remove-method-returns-invalid-record-could-not-find-key-what-sh)